# How to define $_canCapture and $_canCapturePartial protected vars for banktransfer payment?

Tags: configuration, payment

I would like to be able to generate invoice with unpaid status when payment has been made via banktransfer.

I managed to create the invoice, but I read [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/40155/create-invoice-not-paid) that in order to be able to set the status to pending, the $_canCapture and $_canCapturePartial protected vars of the payment method may be set to true.

How can I set these vars properly to true for banktransfer?

Comment: for banktransfer you are using your custom payment method right ?

Comment: if yes you can define and set that var in your payment method

Comment: no, it is the banktransfer of magento, not mine. The vars seems to be defined globally for all the payment methods in Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract. If I change them, it works, but it is not clean...

Comment: you can rewrite model Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Banktransfer

Comment: I overloaded Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract by creating <?php
class Mine_Shipmentmodule_Model_Payment_Method_Abstract extends Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract
{
    protected $_canCapture                  = true;
    protected $_canCapturePartial           = true;
}
?> but it is not taken in account by magento. May I have to add something in the config.xml of my module?

Comment: Without telling Magento that you are re-writing something, it's not gonna be accounted for. You'll need this entry in your config.xml file. See this link for more information : http://inchoo.net/magento/how_to_override_magento_model_classes/

Comment: I tried         <models>
            <shipmentmodule>
                <class>Mine_Shipmentmodule_Model</class>
            </shipmentmodule>
            <payment>
             <rewrite>
                 <method_abstract>Mine_Shipmentmodule_Model_Payment_Method_Abstract</method_abstract>
             </rewrite>
            </payment>
        </models> but not working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks for your help. Here is the full solution :

Impossible to extend abstracts apparently, therefore I went for a banktransfer.php extension

file *Mylib/Mymodule/Model/Payment/Method/Banktransfer.php*

```
<?php
class Mylib_Mymodule_Model_Payment_Method_Banktransfer extends Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Banktransfer
{
    protected $_canCapture                  = true;
    protected $_canCapturePartial           = true;
}
?>
```

then the xml definition : Mylib/Mymodule/etc/config.xml

```
<config>
...
<global>
...
        <models>
            <mymodule>
                <class>Mylib_Mymodule_Model</class>
            </mymodule>

            <payment>
                <rewrite>
                    <method_banktransfer>Mylib_Mymodule_Model_Payment_Method_Banktransfer</method_banktransfer>
                </rewrite>
            </payment>

        </models>
...
</global>
</config>
```

Hope this will help anyone